# xrandr --dpi does not affect Gnome Apps on i3wm

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, xrandr, i3-window-manager

So I used `xrandr --dpi` in order to adjust the dpi of my HiDPI screen on i3wm on Arch (antergos). It seems to have worked well for i3 itself and other apps like Chrome and Telegram, but all the Gnome apps (such as Terminal or Calendar) are not affected by this change and still look very tiny. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was not starting gnome-settings-daemon at launch. It now works properly.